# How to read a large file dictionary and get hash value for each entry? python

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

I have a large file with one string per line. I want to to read this file, get the SHA1 hash value and save both the string and its hash to a file...

so Far I'm at just trying to read the large dictionary file...

```
DictionaryV = []
with open('Dictionary.txt','r') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        DictionaryV.append(eval(line))

print DicionaryV[0]
```

I wanted to print to see if anything loaded. I keep getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script", line 7, in <module>
    DictionaryV.append(eval(line))
 File "<string>", line 1
   !
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

These are the first few lines of the file I'm trying to read:

```
! 
!elephant!
!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!!
!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!1
!!!!!!888888
```

Comment: `eval()` parses a string and executes it as Python code. I do not think this it what you are looking for.

Comment: Why `eval(line)` when appending it to the dictionary?

Comment: Why are you considering your file as a Dictionary file?...I don't see any dictionary format in your file .. ?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want to do. I _think_ you want to read each line from the input file, compute the SHA1 hash for that line, and then save the line with its hash appended to it in the output file. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `eval()` when appending to the dict. 
[eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) will just try to evaluate the string `!` as a python expression which is not what you want.

```
DictionaryV.append(line)
```

You can also get all the lines with `DictionaryV = inf.readlines()` or `DictionaryV = list(f)`.

Also if you are trying to get the SHA1 hash for each string, there is no need for a dictionary, you can compute the SHA1 using functions from [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html):

Answer (score 0):

No need to evaluate the string when you append it to the dictionary:

```
DictionaryV = []
with open('Dictionary.txt','r') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        DictionaryV.append(line)

print DicionaryV
```

Note that `DictionaryV` is a list, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This code reads a text file line by line, strips any trailing white space from the end of the line, computes the SHA1 hash for that line, and then writes the line to the output file with the hexadecimal form of the SHA1 hash appended, with a single space separating the stripped line contents and its hash, and a newline after the hash.

Tested on Python 2.6.6, but it should run correctly on any later versions of Python, too.

```
from hashlib import sha1

iname = 'qdata'
oname = 'qdata_sha1'

with open(iname, 'r') as ifile:
    with open(oname, 'w') as ofile:
        for line in ifile:
            line = line.rstrip()
            digest = sha1(line).hexdigest()
            ofile.write('{0} {1}\n'.format(line, digest))
```

Using the data given in the question as the contents of 'qdata', here's the contents of 'qdata_sha1':

```
! 0ab8318acaf6e678dd02e2b5c343ed41111b393d
!elephant! 750b8da9d4b0a1d2d472afdbec88d74d0d9c3736
!!! 9a7b006d203b362c8cef6da001685678fc1d463a
!!!!! 1227cb28ec9e51942b7dacc0d5453e10d975612f
!!!!!! bae598184569d68359358ff314765c82166f9dfd
!!!!!!! 9b8a410b57694951c5ca9405c741fcc7578af9b1
!!!!!!!! 4cca2690b6ba377b0ed0aae5c6bd746583f34cd6
!!!!!!!!!! f2f7e9980103b41cefff52cb41df97a157de8b40
!!!!!!1 a807638c63c996475e0d1c9bdd84deef9504f7ef
!!!!!!888888 ecd90d1f8bd89fab7001f21a15375f90cfc259c9
```